# How to write radio button value correctly in object in FieldArray?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a dynamic form with checkboxes and radio buttons and for checkboxes it works perfectly, the selected value saves in the correct object. I need the same behavior for radio buttons

Example with radio buttons
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-field-arrays-example-forked-mv127?file=/FieldArraysForm.js

I need an object that looks like this

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionId": 1,
      "question": "question1",
      "questionVariants": [
        {
          "variantId": 1,
          "variantName": "name1",
          "checked": "name1"
        },
        {
          "variantId": 2,
          "variantName": "name2"
        },
        {
          "variantId": 3,
          "variantName": "name3"
        },
        {
          "variantId": 4,
          "variantName": "name4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but now I get

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionId": 1,
      "question": "question1",
      "questionVariants": [
        {
          "variantId": 1,
          "variantName": "name1",
          "checked": "name1"
        },
        {
          "variantId": 2,
          "variantName": "name2"
          "checked": "name2"
        },
        {
          "variantId": 3,
          "variantName": "name3"
          "checked": "name3"
        },
        {
          "variantId": 4,
          "variantName": "name4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can u please elaborate a bit. What is the exact issue? I can see checked property getting updated in below values object.

Comment: Yes, it's updated, but I need to check only one in column (now they don't getting unchecked), and write value only in one object of array.

Comment: So currently whenever you select any radiobutton, its getting checked. But while selecting another radiobutton its not getting unchecked. Thats the problem Right?

Comment: Yep, and save it in right object in an array of variants